# Do all graphs of C1 functions have Hausdorff dimension 1?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Suppose *f* is a real-valued function of one variable, and suppose *f* is of differentiability class C<sup>1</sup>.  My question is, if $\Gamma$ is the graph of *f*, then must $\dim_H(\Gamma)=1$?  If anyone knows of a published proof of the answer, I'd appreciate a reference greatly.

Comment: James: I'm not a specialist, but I doubt mathoverflow is the suitable place to ask this question (see the faq). Have you tried http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is $C^1$, the graph $\Gamma_f$ is locally bilipschitz to $I$, via the projection. It follows that Hausdorff dimension is the same as that of $I$ (being defined in terms of the metric space structure only), so it is $1$.

Disclaimer: I haven't seen these topics for quite a while, so I may have said something stupid.

Comment: A Lipschitz map does not increase dimension.  The map $f$ is Lipschitz on any interval where $f'$ is bounded.  Since $f'$ is continuous, the real line is a countable union of intervals where $f'$ is bounded.  The countable union of sets of dimension at most $d$ also has dimension at most $d$.

Comment: Thank you, I gave for obvious that $(id, f)$ is bilipschitz where $f'$ is bounded. :-) My doubt was whether bilipschitz was enough to preserve the Hausdorff dimension; it should be more or less obvious, but I hadn't seen the definition for like 6 years, and it took me a moment of thinking to convince me that it is so.

Answer (score 1):

In spirit, the solution is in any calculus book, using the length formula
$$L(f) = \int_a^b \sqrt{f'(x)^2+1} dx.$$
You also need the theorem that a continuous function on a closed interval is bounded.